# native code bind to the service in java

Tags: android, android-binder

I have a program written in native c.
And right now,i want this native c program comunicate with the service wriiten in java using bind.
Any one can show me how?
Actually,i have aready tried to do it using local socket.But it is so slow.
thx!

Answer (score 0):

the idea is shown in figure below:

```
 Process P1                                                     Process P2
```

user-space program (in java)

```
   JNI layer


  native code (in c/c++)     <---------------------->     native code (in c/c++)
                                       Binder
```